# PySide6 image being obscured by small box

Tags: pyside6, themoviedb-api

In a group project I am working on, we are creating a movie roulette project. In this project, I and one other have been charged to create the UI. We have a page where we can search for movies and add them to the list to get a random from that list. I want the movie posters to be on the side right beside where it has the title and the overview. I have gotten the picture to show, but for some reason there is a little bar that obscures the picture.[The poster obscured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOxJK.png)
This is where I am creating the label,

```
        self.posterLabel = QLabel(self.posterWidget)
        self.posterLabel.setObjectName(u"posterLabel")
        self.posterLabel.setMinimumSize(QSize(95, 128))
        self.posterLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap(u":/images/images/images/No_Image_Available.jpg"))
        self.posterLabel.setScaledContents(True)
```

and here is where I am setting the poster.

```
                        response = requests.get(self.searchList[i].getPoster())
                        posterImg = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
                        posterImg = ImageQt.toqpixmap(posterImg)
                        widgets.posterLabel.setPixmap(posterImg)
                        print(self.searchList[i].getPoster())
```

I tried to maybe set the stylesheet of the label to have a transparent image as the background image, I tried to set the text before inserting the image to just "", and I tried to turn on autofillBackground, and nothing changed with the picture.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].